# What is the best way to write json objects to a text file and then read them back in?

Tags: python, json, tweepy

I am trying to write a service to read twitter feed stream data and then write it to a file.  I am writing each JSON structure to a line in the file.  With a different service I need to read each line of the file and load the json structure for further operations.

My problem is that I can read the first line then the JSON loader says the rest are not JSON structures.  They look fine.  Not sure what is going on.

Writting file:

```
self.output = open(os.path.join(self.outputdir,self.filename,'w')
self.output.write(status + "\n")
```

Reading File:

```
with open(file) as f:
   line = line.replace("\n","")
   tweet = json.loads(line)
   print tweet['text']
```

raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Example json file:
[JSON File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzxQqOfi4PgETnJRLUNuR2hib2c/view?usp=sharing)

[JSON File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzxQqOfi4PgETnJRLUNuR2hib2c/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The link to the json file does not works.

Comment: You probably can't decode the json because of `line.replace("\n","")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is composed with multiple json objects and empty lines.
You need to load each line as a new json object and ignore empty lines:

```
>>> with open('streamer.151205-071156.json') as f:
>>>    data = [json.loads(l) for l in f if len(l) > 1]
>>> len(data)
7
>>> print(data[0]['text'])
u'Mnjd \U0001f642\U0001f602 https://t.co/BL5Ezxtt0i'
```